# What is solution of inner content scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am having a problem with scroll bar on inner content.
when i hover a arrow on inner content, scroll bar appears that's what i require. But it just change the content that,s look so odd. What the solution for this property.
i want scrrol bar on inner content but dont want change in content?

snap without hovering 
[image]

snap when i hover over inner content 
[image]

[click here to check live link](http://www.softlinked.com/dev/silica/methodology.html)

Comment: Seems it has something related with the browser / OS. In Mac OS, running Chrome, it works ok.

Comment: first of all you need to add a doctype to your html, second you are trowing important on any css value ; Anyway here it work fine , runing firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a scrolling container inside a scrolling window is a BIG no no in User Experience 101.

Your users will be frustrated when they start scrolling and then get stuck inside another scrolling container until they reach the bottom of that container. They will be confused and will not understand what is happening.

I would strongly suggest that you review this approach and instead make you content flow naturally on the page. Your users will thank you :)

If you still want to go ahead with your solution, you will need to apply padding on the inner-rigth side of the scrolling container so that the width of the scrollbar does not push the content and force it to reflow.